# Findby() using two foreign keys with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this "find()" result querying all the data from my 'someTable'.

**someTable**

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5e029b3ca7e71e06464c4c35",
        "someitem": "somedata1",
        "user": {
            "_id": "5de18423bddb7c058f97d57b"
        },
        "hobbie": {
            "_id": "5dec6b377c1e970d8627d8a5"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e039f3fe8d47e18fe940e33",
        "someitem": "somedata2",
        "user": {
            "_id": "5e039ea5e8d47e18fe940e32"
        },
        "hobbie": {
            "_id": "5dec6bc07c1e970d8627d8a8"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e039f6ae8d47e18fe940e34",
        "someitem": "somedata3",
        "user": {
            "_id": "5e039ea5e8d47e18fe940e32"
        },
        "hobbie": {
            "_id": "5dec6bc07c1e970d8627d8a8"
        }
    }
]
```

So, I need to get all **someitemS** filtered by two fields: hobbie._id and user._id, I was researching over the internet but I can not find any clue about this.

**someTable.js (node class with express)**

```
router.get("/my-some-table/:hobbieId", async (req, res, next) => {

  const userId = "5e039ea5e8d47e18fe940e32";
  const hobbieId = req.params.hobbieId;

  // get table data by hobbieId and userId
  const someRegisters = await Some.find(
    {
      user._id: userId, //<--this 'user._id' is generating a sintax error
      hobbie._id: knowId //<--this 'hobbie._id' is generating a sintax error
    }
  );

  res.send(someRegisters);
});
```

**MySchema**

```
const someSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  someitem: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  },
  hobbie: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Hobbie"
  }
});
```

How can I refer to a referenced document id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below query, go inside `user` Object then search, you can also search by global `_id` then you can show your user data.

***example Query:***

```
db.YourColl.find({ "user": { _id: ...}, "hobbie": { _id: ... }} );
```

***Solved Your Problem below, Query:***

```
db.yourColl.find({ "user": { _id: "5e039ea5e8d47e18fe940e32"}, "hobbie": { _id: "5dec6bc07c1e970d8627d8a8"}} )
```